# Html center align the button on media screen

Tags: html, css

I want to align the button horizontally in the same line which is divided into columns in a blue color called `Läs mer` in media screen. following is the link
http://www.visbyhemtjanst.se/

i added the following media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1450px) {
    .home-page-content{
     min-height: 260px;
    }
}
```

when I reduce the screen button doesn't align in the same line what needs to add more in Media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the three columns ( as i can see ) have the same height. so you need your buttons to stay on the bottom of the columns. simply add `position:relative` to the columns and `position:absolute;` to the `buttons` . see code below ( you might need to change it a bit )

also see code snippet below ( i replicated your code from your site )

```
#top .flex_column_table_cell {
    position:relative;
}
.avia-button-center {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
 }
```

```css
#top .flex_column_table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#top .flex_column_table_cell {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
  padding-bottom:30px;
  }



#top .flex_column_table_cell {
    position:relative;
}
.avia-button-center {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="top">
<div class="flex_column_table">
  <div class="flex_column_table_cell">
    
    <h2>Hemtjänst</h2>

     Om du har ett behov att få hjälp med städ, tvätt, personlig omvårdnad eller    ledsagning kan du via Region Gotlands socialförvaltning ansöka om hemtjänst.
Vi är ett privat hemtjänstalternativ  och jobbar på uppdrag av Region Gotland och om du vill anlita oss så planerar vi in ett möte för att planera din hemtjänst.
    <div class="avia-button-center"><a href="#">LAS MER</a></div>
    </div>
  <div class="flex_column_table_cell">
    
    <h2>Personlig assistans</h2>

För dig som har personlig assistans hjälper vi dig med den. Vi rekryterar och tillsätter de assistenter som du själv väljer.

Vi lägger upp din assistans helt utifrån dina villkor. Hör av dig så berättar vi mer vad vi kan erbjuda.
    <div class="avia-button-center"><a href="#">LAS MER</a></div>
    </div>
  <div class="flex_column_table_cell">
    
    <h2>Hushållsnära tjänster</h2>

Vi erbjuder hjälp med hushållsnära tjänster till alla. Oavsett om du har hemtjänst eller inte.

Vi tar hand om det ditt hem så får du tid över till annat.  Genom så kallad RUT avdrag kan du få upp till 50% av kostnaden subventionerad.
    <div class="avia-button-center"><a href="#">LAS MER</a></div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to centre an element add this class

```
.center{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    top:50%;   /*  Adjust this to place it correctly use percentage*/
}
```

Hope this helps